# Негативные последствия максимальной оптимизации

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Есть ли негативные последствия максимальной оптимизации?

К примеру, в `Intel C++ compiler` есть флаги `/O3 /QaxK` и `/O3 /QaxM`.

Comment: Если код написан плохо (c UB), то оптимизация может его сломать.

Comment: Программа будет неработоспособна на процессоре, не поддерживающем соответствующий набор инструкций. Хотя в наше время найти машину не поддерживающею MMX (для /QaxM), надо постараться.

Comment: Для встроенных систем одно из негативных последствий максимальной оптимизации - увеличение объема кода, что приходится учитывать не только в контексте "хватит ли нам памяти", но и иметь в виду время удаленной загрузки, если такой режим поддерживается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оптимизации могут быть разные: по скорости выполнения, по размеру исполняемого файла. Любая оптимизация - это некий дополнительный шаг компилятора. И когда оптимизированная версия начинает вести себя не так как версия без оптимизации, тут возможны обе ситуации: наличие не очевидного на первый взгляд неопределённого поведения в клиентском коде, или вовсе ошибка в коде оптимизации. Безусловно, вероятность первого события намного выше. Когда программу поставляют конечному потребителю имеет смысл включать подходящую оптимизацию, но вот во время разработки (отладки) наличие оптимизаций может затруднять или даже вовсе блокировать возможность пошаговой отладки. Таким образом, надо в первую очередь посмотреть на описание того или иного ключа оптимизации, чтобы в первом приближении понять, какого рода последствий стоит ожидать и что из них может быть воспринято вами, как негативные.